# define json data inside values yaml file

Tags: json, kubernetes, yaml, quarkus, configmap

i have the following inside `application.properties`

```
TEST=[\
  {"name": "max","id": "123","combination": ${COMBINATION_1}]
```

how can i translate this array to a valid `yaml` property inside `Values` file?

is this a valid syntax? i mean with all this defined variables e.g. `combination_1`

```
app:
  pro:
  TEST: |-
    [\
      {"name": "max","id": "123","combination": ${COMBINATION_1}]
  COMBINATION_1: |-
   [\
     {"age": 2, "address": 4}]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64662568/how-can-i-use-a-json-file-in-my-configmap-yaml-helm

Comment: @DreamBold no i need an answer based on my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `\` in a `.properties` file is used for multi-line values. You don't need it in YAML block scalars which are multiline anyway:

```yaml
app:
  pro:
  TEST: |-
    [
      {"name": "max","id": "123","combination": ${COMBINATION_1}}
    ]
  COMBINATION_1: |-
   [
     {"age": 2, "address": 4}
   ]
```

(You can also write everything in a single line below `|-`, or keep the `]` at the end of the line.)

`${COMBINATION_1}` is just a part of a value in YAML, just like it is just a part of a value in `application.properties`. A post-processor needs to take care of it, YAML doesn't do anything with it. Note that I added a `}` after `${COMBINATION_1}` because you also need to close the JSON object.

It is difficult to say more about the variable without knowing which processor does the replacement, but be aware that if it just injects environment variables, `COMBINATION_1` must contain a *valid JSON value*, i.e. if it's a string, the variable must include quotes because unquoted strings are invalid in JSON.